# ANGULAR : show a div element only if another div element has a particular css class and id

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

i am working on an angular app which has a part require to hide a particular show element while another div element has a css class and an Id
the goes goes as below

```html
<div>
  <div class="content"> this div element should show up only below one is there </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <div class="active" id="mainid"> open content </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

content should be shown only while both active class and id available in same div

would like to know is it possible in pure css or typescript also fine as this is a part of angular app

i tried below method

`.content#mainid:not(.content:has(p)) { display: none; }` 
seems like not working

---

Also would like to know is there any way we can do using

> ngIf

like if the div element has 'acitve' class and also "mainid" id

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `div` using the `id` and check if it has the `class` that you want. Now, you can use `ngIf` to render the other `div` conditionally.

Here is an example,

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: ['./your.component.template.ts']
})
export class YourComponent {
  showContent: boolean = false;

  checkElement(): void {
    const targetElement = document.getElementById('mainid');
    if (targetElement && targetElement.classList.contains('class')) {
      this.showContent = true;
    } else {
      this.showContent = false;
    }
  }

}
```

Now, in `your.component.ts` template you can use the `ngIf` directive as below.

```html
<div *ngIf="showContent" class="content">
  this div element should show up only below one is there.
</div>

<div class="active" id="mainid"> open content </div>
```

Now it's up to you how you want to trigger `checkElement()` so that you could control the behaviour i.e. toggle it.
Maybe, add a button or emit some other event.

```html
<button (click)="checkElement()">Hide/Show Content</button>
```

Comment: actually its a navigation #8bitIcon is it possible to make with out triggering any event . its like this actually, once first one is selected supposed to show 
<div class="active" id="mainid"> open content </div>
<div class="" id="mainid2"> open content </div>
<div class="" id="mainid3"> open content </div>

Answer (score 1):

You can easly do that using Angulars **Template Variable**

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="el.classList.contains('active') && el.id === 'mainid'" class="content">
    this div element should show up only below one is there
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <div #el class="active" id="mainid">open content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```